# ¿Se puede sobreescribir una etiqueta de HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo un selector de archivos en HTML junto con JS, y quiero que cuando selecciones una imagen, aparezca en un div. Eso ya esta hecho, pero ahora quiero que cuando selecciones otros archivos, se borren los que ya estaban y aparezcan los nuevos.
en el JS estoy recibiendo el div asi:

```
$("#divPrincipal").html('<div></div>');
```

pero eso parece que lo unico que hace es que me mete el codigo html dentro del mismo div.
¿Hay una manera de sobreescribir el div principal?

Comment: Si se puede, con javascript vanilla se hace igualando el elemento al contenido `id_elemento = '<div><div>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola para eso puede usar dos variantes

```js
function cambiarElemento(){
var div =  document.getElementById('divPrincipal');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'Span Elemento';

div.parentNode.replaceChild(span, div);
}
```

```html
<div id="divPrincipal">Div Principal</div>
<button onclick="cambiarElemento();">Cambiar Elemento</button>
```

de esta forma con js cambiamos un elemento por otro

```js
function cambiarElementoJQuery() {
  var span = $('<span/>', {
    'html': 'Span Elemento',
  });

  $('#divPrincipalJQuery').replaceWith(span)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divPrincipalJQuery">Div Principal</div>
<button onclick="cambiarElementoJQuery();">Cambiar Elemento</button>
```

y de esta forma usando jquery,

En los 2 ejemplos lo que hago es sututuirlos por un span pero puedes sustituirlo por cualquier elemento que desee
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

si se puede sobreescribir es algo asi:

```
//obtencion del elemento
var cajaprincipal = document.querySelector('#divPrincipal');
//sobreescritura
cajaprincicpal.innerHTML = 'codigo html que quieres agregar';
```

Esto sobreescribira lo que esta dentro de tu caja,
el innerHTML borra todo lo que tengas dentro de tu div y te agrega lo que especificaste en el codigo anterior.

si quieres que te agregue mas codigo sin borrar el anterior solo agrega un signo de + despues de innerHTML asi:

```
//obtencion del elemento
var cajaprincipal = document.querySelector('#divPrincipal');
//sobreescritura
cajaprincicpal.innerHTML += 'codigo html que quieres agregar';
```